# How I can I get the mirror reflection of a glm::mat4?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

So I'm using a shader to draw in OpenGL a 2D scene that so far looks like this

[image: flipped scene]

To get this image I have a camera that I use in the shader to multiply the coordinates of the vertex.

Camera code:

```
glm::mat4 projection =
  glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), app.aspectRatio, 0.0f, 100.0f);
glm::vec3 camera = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
glm::mat4 uCameraView = glm::translate(world.projection, world.camera);
```

Shader code:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 vPosition;

layout(std140) uniform ubo
{
  mat4 uCameraView;
};

void main()
{
  gl_Position = uCameraView * vec4(vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

If I multiply by -1 `vPosition.y` in the shader I get the following image, which is the result I want

[image]

Could be possible to somehow apply this "mirror flip transformation" to the `glm::mat4 uCameraView` to avoid having to do this on every shader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirror the y axis of the camera with [`glm::scale`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga05051adbee603fb3c5095d8cf5cc229b). The scale must be (1, -1, 1):

```cpp
glm::mat4 projection = 
    glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), app.aspectRatio, 0.0f, 100.0f);

glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f));
view = glm::scale(view, glm::vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f));

glm::mat4 uCameraView = projection * view;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want a *flipping transformation matrix*, the general version of which is [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection).

In your case you want to flip over `L = (1, 0)`, thus the transformation matrix `A` becomes:

```
[1  0 0 0]
[0 -1 0 0]
[0  0 1 0]
[0  0 0 1]
```

Which in fact can also can be seen as a scaling matrix, as @Rabbid76 pointed out